# Unable to authenticate users with Firebase while using mobile data in Android app,but no error while using wifi

Tags: android, firebase, android-wifi, firebase-authentication

While using Firebase Authentication on Android using  **mobile data**,I am getting the following **error** while running my app:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ Internal error. ]
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacq.zzbN(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacn$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy.zzbO(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzact$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:412)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

But **no error** is shown and authentication happens normally without any error while I run the same app **using wifi**,with the following message instead of the above error:

```
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:2 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:2 
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 2
```

The code that I am using to authenticate/create an user is as follows:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailSignup, passwordSignup)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(LogInSignUp.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                                    {


                                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(LogInSignUp.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            task.getException().printStackTrace();                                                                                      
                                            dialogLoading.cancel();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            String clientUID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                                            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                            DatabaseReference user = database.getReference("clients");
                                            user.push();


                                            ClientProfile c=new ClientProfile();
                                            c.setEmail(emailSignup);
                                            c.setName(nameSignup);
                                            c.setPassword(passwordSignup);
                                            user.child(clientUID).setValue(c);


                                        }


                                    }
                                });
```

I am using

- `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'` in my gradle file
- *google play services vesion 9.0.82* in my phone
- In manifest file:

  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: I am getting a similar error, but it doesn't matter what connection type I am on.  Either way I am getting the error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Has anyone found a solution to it?

Comment: @NehaAgarwal is your error coming up while using mobile data or wifi?

Comment: @Ayan It's coming when I use mobile data. With Wifi everything worked fine.

Comment: got any solution for this?